# Reconstructing string after parsing and modifying numbers from it in Lua

Tags: string, parsing, random, replace, lua

I have strings like the following (quotation marks are only showing that there may be leading and trailing whitespaces), and I need to extract the numbers from the string, which may be integer or float, negative or non-negative.

```
"   M0 0.5 l 20 0 0 20.34 -20 0q10 0 10 10 t 10 10 54.333 10 h -50 z"
```

After extracting the numbers I have to multiply them with random numbers, which the following function produces.

```
-- returns a random float number between the specified boundaries (floats)
function random_in_interval(lower_boundary, upper_boundary)
    return ((math.random() * (upper_boundary - lower_boundary)) + lower_boundary)
end
```

At the end reconstruct the string with the characters and multiplied numbers in the correct order. Also all this has to happen in Lua, and I can't use any external libraries, since this will be used in a LuaTeX compiled document.

The case of the characters must not be changed, characters may or may not have spaces before and after them, but in the output it would be nice if there were. I have already written a helper function to add whitespace before and after characters, however when a character has a whitespace before or after it this will introduce multiple whitespaces, which I cannot solve at the moment.

```
-- adds whitespace before and after characters
function pad_characters(str)
    local padded_str = ""

    if #str ~= 0 then
        for i = 1, #str, 1 do
            local char = string.sub(str, i, i)

            if string.match(char, '%a') ~= nil then
                padded_str = padded_str .. " " .. char .. " "
            else
                padded_str = padded_str .. char
            end
        end
    end

    -- remove leading and trailing whitespaces
    if #padded_str ~= 0 then
        padded_str = string.match(padded_str, "^%s*(.-)%s*$")
    end

    return padded_str
end
```

I have no idea how I could parse, modify the numeric parts of the string, and reconstruct it in the correct order, and doing this in pure Lua without using any external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Adapt as needed.

```
s="   M0 0.5 l 20 0 0 20.34 -20 0q10 0 10 10 t 10 10 54.333 10 h -50 z"

print(s:gsub("%S+",function (x)
    local y=tonumber(x)
    if y then
        return y*math.random()
    else
        return x
    end

end))
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with anything better than processing each character, and decide if it is a number (digit, decimal point, negative sign) or anything else and act according to it.

```
-- returns a random float number between the specified boundaries (floats)
function random_in_interval(lower_boundary, upper_boundary)
    return ((math.random() * (upper_boundary - lower_boundary)) + lower_boundary)
end

-- note: scaling is applied before randomization
function randomize_and_scale(str, scale_factor, lower_boundary, upper_boundary)
    local previous_was_number = false
    local processed_str = ""
    local number = ""

    for i = 1, #str, 1 do
        local char = string.sub(str, i, i)

        if previous_was_number then
            if string.match(char, '%d') ~= nil or
                char == "." then
                number = number .. char
            else -- scale and randomize
                number = number * scale_factor
                number = number * random_in_interval(lower_boundary, upper_boundary)
                processed_str = processed_str .. number .. char
                number = ""
                previous_was_number = false
            end
        else
            if string.match(char, '%d') ~= nil or
                char == "-" then

                number = number .. char
                previous_was_number = true
            else
                processed_str = processed_str .. char
                -- apply stuff
                previous_was_number = false
            end
        end
    end

    return processed_str
end
```